# Term for the unit of grouping large numbers?

Tags: terminology

In English and probably most (if not all) western languages, we group numbers by powers of 1000. So we have:
ones, tens, hundreds - then
thousands, ten-thousands, hundred-thousands - and so on.

We may take this for granted but it's not universal. In Japanese, for example, we have something like:
ichi (ones), jyuu (tens), hyaku (hundreds), sen (thousands) - then
man (ten-thousands), jyuu-man (hundred-thousands), hyaku-man (millions), sen-man (ten-millions) - then
oku (hundred-millions), jyuu-oku (billions), hyaku-oku (ten-billions), sen-oku (hundred-billions)

So my question is: is there a term for this grouping? Can we say something like, "The [term] in english is 10^3 but the [term] in Japanese is 10^4."

Comment: I’ll invent one for you:super-base. But this question isn’t about research mathematics and doesn’t belong here

Comment: That's super-cool. I suppose there some vocabulary overflow where this would be more suitable?

Comment: Try https://english.stackexchange.com/ -- they're knowledgable but not as friendly as here :-)

Comment: these units are _quanta_